# What is `$?` ? Is it a variable?

Tags: command-line, bash

The question is pretty straight forward. I can get the exit code of the previous command by using `$?`. But what exactly is it?

I don't think it is a variable, because you can't have any special characters in the name of variable other than `_`.

```
foo?foo=10
```

will result in the error: `foo?foo=10: command not found`

So if it is not a variable, what is it? Are there others like it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-variable-in-shell-scripting here you go :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

***What is it?***

`$?` is a built-in variable that stores the exit status of a command, function, or the script itself.

`$?` reads the exit status of the last command executed. After a function returns, `$?` gives the exit status of the last command executed in the function. This is Bash's way of giving functions a "return value." It returns `0` on success or an integer in the range `1 - 255` on error.

***Are there others like it too?***

Yes,there are several such built-in variables in bash. You can see a list [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#XSTATVARREF). 
Refer:
 http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Comment: So it's available in bash shell only?

Comment: @daltonfury42 no, any shell that attempts to have some compatibility with the Bourne shell will support it (including `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, among others).

Comment: csh and fish use `$status` for the same purpose

Answer (score 26):

`$?` is a variable but a special one, that's why special characters are allowed.
`($?)` Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

It's not the only one, the shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed :

```
Variable    Meaning
$0          Filename of script
$1          Positional parameter #1
$2 - $9     Positional parameters #2 - #9
${10}       Positional parameter #10
$#          Number of positional parameters
"$*"        All the positional parameters (as a single word) *
"$@"        All the positional parameters (as separate strings)
${#*}       Number of positional parameters
${#@}       Number of positional parameters
$?          Return value
$$          Process ID (PID) of script
$-          Flags passed to script (using set)
$_          Last argument of previous command
$!          Process ID (PID) of last job run in background

* Must be quoted, otherwise it defaults to $@.
```

Sources:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22006

Comment: `"$*"` is not just all positional parameters as a single word, but all positional parameters separated by the first character of `IFS` as a single word. Since the result will be subject to field splitting if not quoted, the effect is as if `$@` is used in the unquoted case.

Comment: To be sure: unquoted $@ and $* are the same because they are _both_ subject to word splitting. Quoted, "$@" preserves the word splitting of the positional parameters, even if an individual parameter contains a character in IFS.

Comment: Is there a reference of since when that is used for shells? I wonder if Perl took those from shell scripting.

Comment: This predates Perl by decades (or at least years). A lot of the Perl syntax was influenced by shell syntax. (Perl was born in 1987, and a lot of this syntax came from the original Bourne shell (1977). I'm not 100% when $_ was introduced, but it was almost certainly well before 1987.

Comment: thank you, I have been find this comment for a long time...

Answer (score 6):

`$?` is a special variable in bash that always holds the **return/exit code** of the last executed command.

You can view it in a terminal by running `echo $?`.

Return codes are in the range [0; 255].
A return code of `0` usually means everything is ok.
Other values indicate errors. Most applications return `1` or custom values.
If a command was not found, the variable usually contains `127`

If you want to set this variable to a specific value, you can easily do this with `bash -c "exit 5"` to return for example the return code `5`.

Comment: A shell function is a POSIX compliant way to set the exit status without necessarily forking. `setstatus() { return 5; }`

Answer (score 6):

`$?` is a **special** shell parameter (variable).

In general all user defined variables must be named by using only the characters from character class `[:alnum:]` i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (also can't begin with `[0-9]`).

In a nutshell, `$?` is a special variable ([and there are quite a few of these](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html)) that can be considered as internal feature of the shell itself that provides the exit code of the previous command (whether succeded or failed).

You can [read this](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) to get more idea on variables.