# Shell script keeps executing even if was true

Tags: scripts, sh

I have a simple shell script to check if the user exist, if not, add that user

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Enter user"
read -r user
if [ "$(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null)" = 1 ]; then
  echo "user existed"
else
  useradd "$user"
  echo "add password"
  passwd "$user"
  echo "$user" &>>text.txt
  echo "saved"
fi
```

But it does not display the `"echo user exist"`. instead it displays like so:

```
Enter user

abcdef

useradd: user 'abcdef' already exists

add password

New password:
```

In this case `abcdef` is an existing user

Please let me know what goes wrong here, thanks a lot.

Comment: A tip to troubleshoot, run the command `id -u testuser` and check if the result is 1. Because 1 is the only thing that will proceed to `echo "User exists"`

Comment: @MatsK Even 1 won't proceed, as the output from `id` is redirected to `/dev/null`.

Comment: After your check of `id -u $user &>/dev/null` use `echo $?` and that will produce either a 0 or 1.  0 meaning `exit code 0` or true, 1 meaning `exit code 1` or false.  Or you can have `if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then`, etc.

Comment: @Terrance It's simpler just to use `id -u $user &>/dev/null` straight away as condition in `if`.

Comment: @raj not in every case.  Actually doing it with `case` statements works very well.  The `id -u` produces the user ID number and not a 1 or 0.  So, outputting `id -u` to >/dev/null will get rid of the 1000 if that is the user ID.

Comment: @Terrance Look at my answer below. Using the command directly as a condition to `if` (without unnecessary `$(...)`) checks it's exit code, not the output.

Comment: @raj That will work too.  Mine is just another way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following condition in your script:

```
if [ "$(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null)" = 1 ]; then
```

will never be true. It would be true **only** if the **output** of command `id -u "$user" &>/dev/null` would be the single digit 1, but as any output from that command is redirected to `/dev/null`, this will never happen.

Replace that line with

```
if { id -u "$user" &>/dev/null ; } then
```

This condition checks the **exit status** of the command (and not its **output** like `$(...)` does) and will be true if the command `id -u "$user" &>/dev/null` **succeeds** (that is, user exists) and false if it **fails** (that is, user doesn't exist).

Comment: Thank for your answer, it work!!v But what different between [] and {}?

Comment: `[` is a **command** (equivalent to `test`; see `man [`) used to check the result of various conditional expressions. `{}` are just parentheses to enclose the command. Actually, we may skip `{}` altogether (while you **cannot** skip `[]`): `if id -u "$user" &>/dev/null ; then` will work as well only is less readable.

Comment: i sitll dont understand `[` is a command to check the value, then, in my command '"$(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null)" = 1` why it not return true, i mean, `"$(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null)"` will return 0 or 1 right?

Comment: The value of `$(command)` is the **output** of the command, ie. the text the command prints. Because you redirect that output to `/dev/null`, the command prints nothing. So the value of `$(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null)` will be always **an empty string**. You compare that empty string to the digit 1, which can never return true.

Comment: The `{` and `}` are superfluous. `if id -u "$user" &>/dev/null; then` is enough.

Comment: @JanHudec I know, but the code is more clear with `{}`. They are ther just for style :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @raj is 100% correct for simplifying code.

These are just some alternate ways of using the exit codes and maybe shedding a little more light in how they can be used.

The exit code can be checked by doing an `echo $?` right after your command of `id -u $user &>/dev/null` which doesn't need to be encased in `$(..)` or anything like that.

Just try `id -u <username> &>/dev/null` and then type in `echo $?` to check the exit code.

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ id -u terrance &>/dev/null
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ echo $?
0
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ id -u mark &>/dev/null
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ echo $?
1
```

*In the above example, the user `mark` does not exist on my computer thus the exit status of 1.*

Using the exit code you can put it into a `case` statement instead of an `if..else` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter username"
read -r user
id -u "$user" &>/dev/null
case $? in
    0) echo "User exists";;
    1) adduser $user
       echo "add password"
       passwd $user
       echo $user >> text.txt
       echo "saved";;
esac
```

Interestingly enough, using an `if [ ]; then` can still be used as well by adding an `echo $?` into your if check, but I did notice that you were checking for 1 to be if exist, but 1 means that the code exited with 1 meaning not found.

Adding it will work like this as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter username"
read -r user
if [ $(id -u "$user" &>/dev/null; echo $?) == 0 ]; then
    echo "User exists"
else
    adduser $user
    echo "add password"
    passwd $user
    echo $user >> text.txt
    echo "saved"
fi
```

Comment: Thank, i learn a lot from your answer, but i dont understand why `echo $` ,what is that ??

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Maybe this here might shed a little more light on the `echo $?` for checking exit commands:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/646526/what-is-is-it-a-variable

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Also, when made the check as `id -u "$user" &>/dev/null; echo $?` it is now 2 commands as 1.

Comment: It's a life-hack for shell bash =) ,thank you a lots

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh You are very welcome!

Comment: Can i ask you another ques? I know `&>` will move stdout and stderr to , but in this case why do we need move these value to `/dev/null` , all i understand now is `id -u "$user" &>/dev/null` return 0 or 1, then move to `/dev/null` But all we need is check check is was  0 or 1, but why we need move to   `/dev/null` , if i use only ` id -u "$user" &>/dev/null` , what happend? Actually this code from our website and not totally understand

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Using `/dev/null` is a way to basically erase the stdout from you seeing it on the screen.  It is just a way to keep the stuff clean.  You can get the same exit code or status without using it, but you will see all that output to the screen and it might make it more difficult to use your code.  Feel free to test your code without the `&>/dev/null` as it should still work.

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh The 0 and 1 is only the exit status.  If you run `id -u $user` without anything after it, it will produce the user ID number.  Like my username produces 1000 as that is my user ID number.  But, if I type in `echo $?` after that command it will still produce a 0 since the exit status passed.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: I just try to log by  `user1="$(id -u "$user")"` and 
`echo "User is $user1"` and it return  1007, what that mean?

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh `id -u` produces the UID or the user ID number not the exit status.  You have to run `echo $?` as the next command to see what the exit status of the command `id -u` is.

Comment: I understand now, thank you a lot